# JS Remove Entries from 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Totally newbie to JS so apologise for the probably obvious solution to this issue!

I'm trying to write a bit of code for use in google sheets that basically removes elements of a 2D array if the 3rd value in each nested array is empty eg.

`[[1,2,3],[4,5,,],[7,8,9],[,,,]`

would become

`[[1,2,3],[7,8,9]]`

I've currently got:

```
if (bkLoc=='HALL'){
      var sumRng = sh.getRange('MIC_SUMM').getValues();
      for (var i =0; i<sumRng.length ; i++){
        if(sumRng[i][2] !== (undefined || '' || null)){
          micSumm.push(sumRng[i]);
        }
      }
    }
```

But the output seems to contains loads of empty arrays almost like its pushing every loop and I'm not sure why.

Any help would be gratefully received!

EDIT1: So with the help of you guys I got it to work. Using Nikhils answer I am now using this for the IF

```
if (bkLoc=='HALL'){
      var sumRng = sh.getRange('MIC_SUMM').getValues();
      for (j =0; j<sumRng.length ; j++){
        var x = sumRng[j][2];
        if(x != 0 && x != '??'  && x != undefined){
          micSumm.push(sumRng[j]);
        }
      }
    }
```

But to be honest I don't really understand it. My understanding was || is OR so in my original code

`if(sumRng[i][2] !== (undefined || '' || null))`

If the tested content DOESN'T CONTAIN undefined OR "" OR null , the if statement should be true. I thought && meant AND so I'm unclear as to why that ever passes

Apologies for being so dumb!

Cheers

Comment: **Warning to answerers:** Google Apps Script is **not** modern JavaScript. It's roughtly ES3 plus a bit, and doesn't have most of ES5 and certainly not any ES2015+.

Comment: Use `Array.filters()` function. `sumRng[i][2] !== (undefined || '' || null))` is really wrong.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Is that available in sheets?

Comment: @ArupRakshit - There is no standard `Array.filters` function. If you meant `Array#filter` (singular), not in GAS, see my first comment above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes my bad it was a typo.

Comment: @I'-'I - Thanks, good to know.

Comment: In the statement `if (sumRng[i][2] !== (undefined || '' || null)`, the `(undefined || '' || null)` is evaluated first to `('' || null)` and then to `(null)` and then `null`, and then it is compared to `sumRng[i][2]`. [This is because the logical OR returns the RHS if the LHS is not evaluable to `true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description) I.e. it becomes `if (sumRng[i][2] !== null)`. The innermost element result of `Range#getValues()` will have either a value, or `""`, never `null`, so that statement will always be true.

Answer (score 3):

In your current `if` condition, `undefined || '' || null` evaluates to `null`. Hence, the condition eventually becomes `sumRng[i][2] !== null`.

However, as you need to check for `undefined` and `''` too, you will need to update your condition

From

```
if(sumRng[i][2] !== (undefined || '' || null)){
```

to

```
if(sumRng[i][2] !== undefined && sumRng[i][2] !== '' && sumRng[i][2] !== null){
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've defined `micSumm` somewhere and started out with a blank array in it (`var micSumm = [];`), then you're on the right track, the issue is here:

```
if(sumRng[i][2] !== (undefined || '' || null)){
```

That's not how you do a check against multiple values in JavaScript. The way that's evaluated is:

1. `sumRng[i][2]` is evaluated; let's call the resulting value `left`
2. `undefined || ''` is evaluated, the result is `''`; let's call it `temp`¹
3. `temp || null` (`'' || null`) is evaluated, the result is `null`; let's call that `right`
4. The result of `left !== right` is evaluated

So you end up only checking for `null`, not `undefined` or `''`.

Instead:

```
var value = sumRng[i][2];
if (value !== undefined && value !== '' && value !== null) {
```

Or you can take advantage of the fact `!= undefined` also checks for `null`:

```
var value = sumRng[i][2];
if (value != undefined && value !== '') {
```

...but that can be a bit less clear.

---

¹ Why does `undefined || ''` result in `''`? Because an expression `a || b` is evaluated like this:

1. Evaluate `a`
2. If the value from Step 1 is *truthy*, make that the result of the `||` operation
3. Otherwise, evaluate `b` and make that the result of the `||` operation

`undefined` is *falsy*, not *truthy*. (A *falsy* value is any value that coerces to `false` when used as a boolean. The falsy values are `undefined`, `null`, `""`, `0`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`. All other values are *truthy*.)

Comment: `!==` is always better than `!=` :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit - I don't agree with that as an absolute. But I'd use `!==` here.

Comment: I am not challenging, but asking here. Does coercion is a good feature? I think implicit things are some times not good.

Comment: @ArupRakshit - In general, I agree that explicit is better than implicit. I just don't generally go for absolute rules, because it seems like there's always an exception.

Comment: FWIW !== seems to be one of the causes of all the blank entries. Changing it to != helped. TJ: can you possible explain why || doesn't work? I thought that was OR and && was AND??

Comment: @ChrisBarrett - They do, but `!==` only compares two operands, the one on the left and the one on the right. By the time `!==` happens, `undefined || '' || null` has already been evaluated and the result is `null`. I've added the steps to the answer. (You don't want to use `sumRng[i][2] != (undefined || '' || null)`, because that's just `sumRng[i][2] != null`. It'll be true for `null` and `undefined` (because of the coercion rules `!=` applies), but won't be true for `''`.)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use filter(which is supported by apps-script):

```
var filteredArr =  sumRng.filter(function(e) {return e[2];})
```

Note that you're getting a 2D array with a specific rectangular dimension. So, there's no possibility of a value being `undefined`. Unless you specifically made a value `null`,`null` isn't returned. As noted in the comments below, the above also filters out 0 and boolean false. So, You can use

```
sumRng.filter(function(e) {return e[2].toString();})
```

or

```
sumRng.filter(function(e) {return e[2] || e[2] === false || e[2] === 0;})
```

References:

[Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
[Primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)
[null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null)
[Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)
[Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Comment: If, as you say in a comment on the question, GAS supports `filter`, you should state that explicitly in your answer. But note that your answer doesn't do what the OP's code does; yours also filters out several other falsy values, including `0`, `NaN`, `false`...

Comment: @TJ In terms of values that Google Sheets will send to an array, `NaN` won't happen. I'd use `return e[2] || e[2] === false || e[2] === 0;` to handle the Boolean and 0 cases. I'd also chain the filter directly on `getValues()`.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help everyone. But I'm still a bit confused. I tried the filter code and it seems to work the same as my original code in that the array I'm pushing to still gets filled with a load of empty entries which is just bizarre. I can't see how it ever gets into that part of the IF statement.

Answer (score 1):

I still struggle with the why the original OR method I had doesn't work. In fact I went over to reddit to try and see if I could get anymore clarification but still it won't go in. But I appreciate all your help trying.

I did get an alternative solution to my conundrum though which seems a more condensed version of what I was using. That was simply this (courtesy of user insertAlias)

```
if(sumRng[i][2]){}
```

Apparently that will only pass for anything truthy so seems to fit the bill. But please point out any shortcomings

Comment: if the value is `false` or `0` in your 3rd column, then your statement will treat it as though its value were `""` (i.e. nonexistent)